# Is there a way to recover a macOS Sierra Preview behaviour in macOS Mojave about LaTeX-typed PDFs?

Tags: pdf, preview

I type most of my documents with LaTeX.

Since I upgraded my Mac from macOS Sierra to macOS Mojave, links in the PDFs are displayed with a red box around them:

[image]

However, when I open the same PDF in Google Chrome, red boxes are not displayed (as did Preview when I was on macOS Sierra).

I know there is the `hidelinks` option when calling the `hyperref` package, but this fixes the problem at the time of compilation, and I want to remove the boxes in all the PDFs I already compiled.

(It is more a question of personal comfort when viewing a PDF on my Mac than a big problem here.)

I don't know if this behaviour is specific to Preview in macOS Mojave, but maybe Apple brought some improvements to it, and it is maybe modifiable with a command in the terminal?

Comment: Is your TEX package up to date ?

Comment: If you mean that I'm running on the 3.14159265 TeX version, then yes!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to be moved to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154873/whats-new-in-tex-version-3-14159265/154876#154876

Comment: you should try your question at our TEX specific website https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't really know if this is TeX-related, since it clearly is Preview that keeps showing these boxes in macOS Mojave, they weren't there in Sierra

Comment: TEX worked fine with Sierra and Preview. TEX has problems with Mojave and Preview. I would say it is TEX.

Comment: I had this behaviour both in High Sierra and Mojave. More, I had seen it in Acrobat Reader on Windows, on some documents picked up on the internet, either in red, either in blue. Looking further for a solution.

Comment: @Yoan Yes I guess it is a normal behaviour from the `hyperref` package in LaTeX, as I understand it, the red links are internal to the document and blue ones are external links. I think that the information of these boxes is somewhere in the PDF document, but somehow it wasn’t used by Preview in macOS Sierra?

Comment: I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126089/red-boxes-around-hyperlinks and seems to be related to tex engine used. Hiding  link works, but that is not an option. I always had that in Preview, even in Sierra.